# ifconfig not showing the correct ip address

Tags: 16.04, networking, dns, ip, ifconfig

There is an `Ubuntu` server *(16.04.02 LTS)* running on vm in production.

From Internet I can ssh to it via `xxx.xxx.xxx.27`, I can also access the websites on it via both ip *(xxx.xxx.xxx.27)* and hostname.

But after login to it via ssh, `ifconfig` show that the ip address is `xxx.xxx.xxx.29`.

`cat /etc/network/interfaces` shows the ip is static and is `xxx.xxx.xxx.27`.

Even though it seems not causing any issue for websites running on the server currently, but it's weird.

**The questions are:**

- Why `ifconfig` shows the wrong ip?
- How could I correct that?

---

**@Update**

It seems that I could also access the websites via `xxx.xxx.xxx.29`, does it means there are 2 ip addresses bounded to the server from vm management tools *(which is not in my control)*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably nothing to correct.  You didn't provide the complete IP addresses but unless your company is swimming in class B or C addresses it's  possible that the machine is behind a firewall using NAT addresses or local, unroutable IP addresses.

An easy way to check this is to type:

traceroute IP

traceroute hostname

Do this from the Internet and on the local VM.  And using xxx.xxx.xxx.27 and 29.

Of course it's possible that the machine in question has multiple DNS records.  To check this, type:

dig hostname

Also dig -x IP - In case there is some reverse lookup records in play. Again, do this with .27 and .29.

I don't know about Ubuntu specifically but many *NIX distros use common network connections amongst virtual machines.  Virtual sockets of the 192.168.0.x variety would be found by running ifconfig.

I'm assuming that the machine in question has a single NIC card and a single network connection.